# What are the max skill points Class Mods can grant?

Tags: borderlands-2

For Borderlands 1, maximum bonus was +4/3/3, making maximum level for single skill 9. For Borderlands 2 there is no specific information on any of the wikis, except for "Legendary" and "Slayer of Terramorphous" mods, which give +5 and +4 respectively.

What are maximum skill bonuses from any Class Mods?

Comment: Legendary/slayer class mods are the best in the game so far, and the only legendaries, so they're indeed the highest skill point bonuses.

Comment: Nope... I've seen a +6/5 on some random Mod in some videos (oh, like the one celion attached below). I wonder if it is the max, and if there are mods with three skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some non-legendaries have +6 to a skill. Never seen more than 6, though from my inventory even a green can have a level 6, so I don't think it's tied necessarily to rarity (it may be to level though, these are level 50 mods and I think lower level ones go as low as +1). I've played 4 full playthroughs (two playthrough ones, two playthrough twos) and I don't recall ever seeing a single +7, though I have a few +6s in my inventory right now.

The skill counts are the same as the first game; white mods have no skills they boost, greens boost 1, blue 2, purple 3.

According to [The Gear Calculator](http://thegearcalculator.appspot.com/) (via [Orc JMR](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/33619/orc-jmr)), green Mods can grant up to +5, blue Mods up to +6/5, purple Mods up to +5/4/4. So Purple mods boast the most skill points overall, but blue mods can actually boost two specific skills higher than a purple can.

Legendary mods have set skills they boost, the Legendary (Class) mod boosts by +5, the Slayer of Terra mods have +4.

Comment: What are your observations on three-skill mods, are they up to +6/5/5? +6/5/4?

Comment: @OrcJMR it's not preset. One skill tends to be above the others, I've seen 6/4/4 and 6/5 for two skills, I would assume 6/5/5 is possible but very rare

Comment: According to [The Gear Calculator](http://thegearcalculator.appspot.com/), green Mods can grant up to +5, blue Mods up to +6/5, purple Mods up to +5/4/4.

Comment: @OrcJMR Ah, the gear calculator! Great idea, thanks. that seems to match my personal experience for sure. Interesting that a blue mod might actually be *better* if you only have 2 skills you want to boost

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video at around 3:38

They find a Legendary Mechromancer Class Mod with +5 to 6 skills BUT a penalty to cooldown too.

I'm not sure if that's the max, but it's still pretty big :)

Comment: Yup, some Mods do have penalties - that is just how some of them are, it does not improve skillbonuses, AFAIK (not every mod can hav e penalties at all).